# NVME timeout, aborting when playing games

Tags: linux, btrfs, nvme

When playing certain games the game will hang and a whole bunch of NVME errors followed by BTRFS errors will be dumped to `dmesg`.

The end result of this is the filesystem being mounted as read only and I'm forced to reboot my computer.

I've tried changing up my mount options, specifically I've used `noatime`, `nodiratime`, and `nospace_cache` to see if any of those maybe make any kind of difference but so far nothing.

Is there anything I can do to further diagnose this, what could be causing it, and how can I fix it?

My kernel is from 5.2.7 from kernel.org however it happens on pretty much every kernel version I've tried.

[dmesg output](https://pastebin.com/Pa35BKGa)

[smartctl --all output](https://pastebin.com/nbte5hiY)

Comment: Have you checked the health of the disk with `smartctl`?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa The health check passed but I attached the output of `smartctl --all /dev/nvme0n1` just in case I'm missing something.